# How can I use Selenium Webdriver for Firefox (Geckodrive)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I want to use Selenium Webdriver of Firefox in colab.research.google.com.
I tired to use some code but It did not work out and was showing an error in the second last line.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
ser=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser)
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

The error message shown is

**====== WebDriver manager ======
Could not get version for firefox with the command: firefox --version
Current firefox version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST geckodriver version for UNKNOWN firefox
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.30.0/geckodriver] found in cache**
Would really appreciate if someone can help me out
Thanks

Comment: update your firefox to the latest version, download the latest version of geckodriver compatible with your firefox version. you can then use `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='../../<path to geckodriver.exe'`

Comment: Because I am learning that this error message does not always mean what it says...
1. Check that '/usr/bin/firefox' exists and is a binary.
2. Run '/usr/bin/firefox -version' on the command line and see what comes out.
I ran into this error because I did not have a binary in my new container.